# Android Studio quiz app with score

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm currently making a flag quiz app in Android Studio, and I want to add a feature where each correct answer gives you 1 point, and wrong answer gives you 0. (pressing the hint button or skip button also gives you 0). At the end, you can press a button called "get my score" where the final score is given.

My problem is that even when I submit correct answers, my score is 0, whereas when I submit wrong answers, then sometimes my score is positive... Aka something is wrong. Am I missing some code, or have I simply done this the wrong way?

**Update**

Managed to do it! The correct code is below.

First, this is kinda the main activity, with the code for all fragments (flags):

**Play.java**

```
public class Play extends MainActivity {

private int total = 0;

public void updateScore(int add){
    total += add;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

    final String myScore = String.valueOf(total);

    final ImageButton imageBtn10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton10);
    final ImageButton imageBtn9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton9);
    final ImageButton imageBtn8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);
    final ImageButton imageBtn7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
    final ImageButton imageBtn6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
    final ImageButton imageBtn5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    final ImageButton imageBtn4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    final ImageButton imageBtn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

    final Button button_score = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scoreButton);


    FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
    FragmentDefault fd = new FragmentDefault();
    fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fd);
    fragTrans.commit();

    fragTrans.hide(new FragmentOne());
    fragTrans.hide(new FragmentTwo());
    fragTrans.hide(new FragmentThree());

    button_score.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("yes", String.valueOf(total));

            Intent intent= new Intent(Play.this, FinalActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    imageBtn10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
                fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_place, new FragmentOne());
                fragTrans.commit();
                //imageBtn10.setEnabled(false);
        }

    });


    imageBtn9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
            fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_place, new FragmentTwo());
            fragTrans.commit();
        }
    });

    imageBtn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
                fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_place, new FragmentThree());
                fragTrans.commit();
        }
    });

    imageBtn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
            fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_place, new FragmentThree());
            fragTrans.commit();
        }
    });

    imageBtn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
            fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_place, new FragmentThree());
            fragTrans.commit();
        }
    });

    imageBtn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
            fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_place, new FragmentThree());
            fragTrans.commit();
        }
    });

    imageBtn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
            fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_place, new FragmentThree());
            fragTrans.commit();

        }
    });

    imageBtn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
            fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_place, new FragmentThree());
            fragTrans.commit();
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Code for the first flag(fragment):

**FragmentOne.java**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    private EditText userAnswer;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, null);
    userAnswer = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.showCorrect);
    final TextView hintv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textHint);

    final Button submit = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.submitBtn1);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String theAnswer = (userAnswer.getText().toString());
            if (theAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("Germany")) {
                ((Play) getActivity()).updateScore(1);
                tv.setText("Correct!");
            }
            else {
                tv.setText("Wrong");
            }
            submit.setEnabled(false);

            // updateScore();
        }
    });

    final Button skip = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.skipBtn);
    skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            submit.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    final Button hint = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.hintBtn);
    hint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hintv.setText("The capital is Berlin \n The country is in Europe \n It starts with G... ");
        }
    });
    return v;}
}
```

This is the code for one of the questions. So you can click on a flag and write which country is belongs to. Each flag is a fragment.

I get an error in the code above due to this line:
((Play) getActivity()).updateScore(1);
Play is colored red, and it says 'Cannot resolve symbol 'Play''.

This is the code for when you have pressed the "get my score" button:

**FinalActivity.java**

```
public class FinalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_final);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String yes_sir = bundle.getString("yes"); //yes_sir has to be the total score added up.

    final TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    final Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            tv2.setText("Score is " + yes_sir);
        }
    });
}
}
```

I'm a complete beginner at programming, so a detailed explanation would be most helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You get your score from the bundle using the key "yes":

```
 final String yes_sir = bundle.getString("yes");
```

I guess your score should be "a", because your are increasing this, when the answer is correct. You don't show us the code, where you change the view to the score view (creating the new Activity) and where you add the score to the bundle. You should add the score to the bundle in your fragment classes like this:

```
bundle.putString("yes", String.valueOf(a));
```

You can use the Android Bundles to give Data to a new Activity. To do that you can **put** data into a Bundle and give it to the onCreate of your new Activity. There you can **get** the Data back. Your problem is, that you are trying to **get** data from the Bundle, but never **added** data to it.

To help you more detailed it would be usefull to see the code, where you are creating the Activity showing the Score.

You need to give that Bundle to your new Activity using the Intent.

When you want to start your FinalActivity, you should do something like this:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this, FinalActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

To communicate between Fragments and its Activity the easiest (but not the best) way is the following:

((Play) getActivity()).updateScore(1);

Do this in your Fragments, instead of the public static int. So instead of your "a++;" you write the line above.

In your Play class you have to add the function:

```
public void updateScore(int add){
    total += add;
}
```

You should change:

```
 final int total = (0 + FragmentOne.a + FragmentTwo.b);
```

To:
     private int total = 0;

And move it from the onCreate() function into the class.

Instead of:

```
bundle.putString("yes", myScore);
```

You can now do:

```
bundle.putString("yes", String.valueOf(total));
```

**NOTE:** Your problems occured, because your score was initialized once, when you create the Play Activity. That means, when you first initialized it, the total would be set to 0. When you now answer a question correctly, total would not be updated, because it is only set, wehn you initialize your Activity. When you press the Score Button it is still 0. When you switch now back to your Play Activity, the total is initialized again and becomes 1 (if you answred correctly befor).

Comment: so I have altered my code and you can see the new code below. Though, program doesn't run..

Comment: Yeah, you miss understand me. Please update your question, istead of adding an answer. That is not the way SO works. I updated my answer.

Comment: the Activity showing the score is FinalActivity.java that I have provided above.

Comment: I know. But how are you starting it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132560/discussion-between-galexmes-and-kara-w).